# Why does \restoregeometry not align enumerate environments properly?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, geometry

Can you tell me why the sub-enumerate environment isn't horizontally aligned after using `\restoregeometry`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\newgeometry{} \restoregeometry
\item \lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2] %Why is the right hand side of this paragraph not horizontally aligned with the rest of the text?
\end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate non-alignment]

Comment: both commands are intended to be used at the top level, if you use it mid-list nothing good is likely to happen.

Comment: I think the reason is that the `\leftmargini` etc. values are used before the new level of enumeration starts and inserting new geometry layout does  update the `\leftmargini` values, but enumerate does not reevaluate those registers

Answer (score 2):

\newgeometry resets \linewidth to the default \textwidth. You can reset is to the  correct value for the list like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item aa
 \newgeometry{} \restoregeometry
 \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin
 \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin
\item \lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2] %Why is the right hand side of this paragraph not horizontally aligned with the rest of the text?
\end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But on the whole it would be better not to use \newgeometry in the middle of an environment. It doesn't expect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\newgeometry{} \restoregeometry
\begin{enumerate} \setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item \lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you would use the `enumitem` package, you could even apply the `resume` key such that you don't need to store the `enumi` counter. If you have a second level list, your approach is error-prone, I think